# Prove the inner product on C^1[0,1] is bigger than its supreme

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

prove that $ \forall f$ in $C^{1}[0,1]$, if $(f,g)=\int_0^1fg+f'g' dx$, then there exist $C>0$ , s.t. $C*(f,f)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq sup(|f|)$
Assume that f(r)=max(|f|), I have proven that if   min(|f|)=0, the result can be got easily. But how to prove the result when the function is always bigger than 0 on [0,1]?

Comment: As it stands this is a problem-statement with no context or effort and will likely get closed for those reasons.  Please explain what you've tried and where you are stuck as this, if nothing else, will help answerers understand the level they need to pitch answers at.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get the answer by myself. When $f>0, \forall x \in [0,1]$, then assume f(s)=min(f)Since there is no zero point on [0,1], we just need to prove the case of f>0). Then $(\int_0^1 f^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq min(f)=f(s)$ and f(r)-f(s)=$\int_s^r f’dx \leq (\int_0^1 (f’)^2 dx)^ {\frac{1}{2}}$ .That lead to the conclusion.